# Sort an arraylist of custom object in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

There is an object like this:

```
dataObj
=============
name
address
isTopPriority
```

So I have an arrayList of dataObj, how to sort the dataObj to "if isTopPriority is true, then they will be the fronter part of the array" ? Thanks

Attempt the code like:

```
private class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Spot> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Spot lhs, Spot rhs) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return lhs.isStar.compareTo();
        }
    }
```

But I am confused about why to compare between 2 object , I would like to comapre like this:

just `if (currentObj.isFirstPriority == true) then return the object`.

Thanks for helping

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Comparator` "has" to return -1 if `rhs` is "more" than `lhs`, 0 if they're equal and 1 if it's less. This is so the sorting is actually consistent (if you sort `rhs` comparing it to `lhs` and `lhs` comparing it to `rhs` it has to have the opposite result, or 0). The following `Comparator` does that:

```
private class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Spot> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Spot lhs, Spot rhs) {
        if (lhs.isStar == rhs.isStar) return 0;
        else if (lhs.isStar) return 1;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

You also have to actually sort it, but I'm guessing you know how to do that (`Collections.sort(arrayList, comparator)`).

Comment: the problem is it seems the sort is reverse, that means the star item is lower prioirty

Answer (score 1):

This will sort primary by priority, and secondary by name.

```
private static final Comparator<Data> dataComparator = new Comparator<Data>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Data o1, Data o2) {
        if (o1.isTopPriority() && o2.isTopPriority())
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        if (o1.isTopPriority())
            return 1;
        if (o2.isTopPriority())
            return -1;
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
};
```